# how to checked checkboxes in edit page where i define name="radio[$type->id][]" in multidimenssional array. How to do this in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I also used:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="radio[{{ $type->id }}][]" value="1" id="radio{{ $type->id }}" class="form-control" {{ (is_array(old('radio["$type->id"][]')) && in_array(1 ?? [], old('radio["$type->id"][]'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@foreach($types as $type)
    <input type="radio" name="choice[]" id="1" value="1" class="form-check-input" {{ ($type->id == 1) ? 'checked' : ''}} >
@endforeach
```

Comment: My name="" attribute is in multidimenssional array

Comment: Problem: How to define in old('...') function to checked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).